# SSIS version compatibility issues

Tags: ssis, version

I built a ssis package in 2017 in my local machine which had 2017 version.
Since SSIS server is installed on 2016, I changed the target version to 2016 and built it and generated ispac file.
When the deployment team used the .ispac file to deploy the project in stage and prod server, it gets converted to 2017 again and fails with version issues.
I tried multiple times to change target version, rebuild and redeploy them, still same issue persists.
Can someone please help!

Answer (score 0):

The .ispac file on disk is likely 2016 as that's the target build model. However, the deployment tool you're using is likely 2017 based and is thus upgrading the project in memory before it deploys it.

- 2016 aka 130
- 2017 aka 140

The most common options to deploy an ispac is through the "IS Deployment Wizard " (Visual Studio uses this and windows likely has associated the .ispac file extension to be opened by this tool) or through "SQL Server Management Studio" (SSMS)

Depending on your set up, you might have multiple versions of these tools installed and my guess is that the 140 based binaries are deploying your code. For example, my system shows the following installs available but the 140 is the "first" one in my system PATH variable so by default, I use the SQL Server 2017 binaries unless I explicitly use otherwise.

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\140\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SSIS\140\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe

or launch SSMS 2016 (if you have it installed) and use the SSIS project deployment from there

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe